# How to run an application in background in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm using selverlight to make an application like an alarm for meetings and events.

I want the program to start automatically when the phone is turned on, and keep running in the background.

Another important point is how can I reach the program from the Emulator when it is hidden, or set to background. In windows application we can do that using a small icon on the taskbar, but here in WP7, how can this be possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Application can't run in background all the time. You can use [Background Agent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202942%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) and [Alarms and Reminders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202965%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) for this.